# Multiplicative aggregation with AVX

Tags: simd, avx, avx2, avx512

I have an array `x[1],x[2],..,x[n]` and I want to multiply K consecutive elements so as to obtain the new array `x[1]*..*x[K], x[K+1]*x[K+1]*..*x[2*K], ...` and so on. You can assume the length of `x` is n, and that K divides n. Hence, the length of the new array is n/K.

How would I do this in AVX (given there is no horizontal multiply)?

For simplicity, I will accept an analysis for K = 3, or K = 4, though I would prefer an answer wihch applies for all K between 2 (inclusive) and 4 (inclusive).

Answer (score 2):

You’re correct about the lack of horizontal multiplies, but there’re various shuffles.

For AVX, shuffles come in two kinds: the instructions which shuffle stuff within 16-byte lanes of the vectors are very cheap, while the shuffles which move data across the complete vectors are generally more expensive.

Fortunately, if your source data is in memory, the expensive shuffles are avoidable at the cost of a few more load instructions. The `vinsertf128` instruction can load 16 bytes of data into the higher half of the vector, with no overhead compared to regular 16-bytes load. Here’s a reasonably efficient implementations for your 3 cases. Note that when the length of your input vector is not divisible by K*4, you’ll need to handle the remainder with scalar code.

```
// Load a vector with the following values: a[0], a[1], b[0], b[1]
inline __m256d load2( const double* a, const double* b )
{
    // This function should compile into 2 instructions
    __m256d vec = _mm256_castpd128_pd256( _mm_loadu_pd( a ) );
    return _mm256_insertf128_pd( vec, _mm_loadu_pd( b ), 1 );
}

// Load 8 numbers, return a vector of [ 0*1, 2*3, 4*5, 6*7 ]
inline __m256d horizontalMultiply2( const double* rsi )
{
    __m256d a = load2( rsi, rsi + 4 );      // 0, 1, 4, 5
    __m256d b = load2( rsi + 2, rsi + 6 );// 2, 3, 6, 7
    return _mm256_mul_pd( _mm256_unpacklo_pd( a, b ), _mm256_unpackhi_pd( a, b ) );
}

// Load 12 numbers, return a vector of [ 0*1*2, 3*4*5, 6*7*8, 9*10*11 ]
inline __m256d horizontalMultiply3( const double* rsi )
{
    __m256d a = load2( rsi, rsi + 6 );      // 0, 1, 6, 7
    __m256d b = load2( rsi + 2, rsi + 8 );  // 2, 3, 8, 9
    __m256d c = load2( rsi + 4, rsi + 10 ); // 4, 5, 10, 11

    __m256d r = _mm256_blend_pd( a, b, 0b1010 );// 0, 3, 6, 9
    // The multiplier is [ 1, 4, 7, 10 ]
    r = _mm256_mul_pd( r, _mm256_shuffle_pd( a, c, 0b0101 ) );
    // The multiplier is [ 2, 5, 8, 11 ]
    r = _mm256_mul_pd( r, _mm256_blend_pd( b, c, 0b1010 ) );
    return r;
}

// Load 16 numbers, return a vector of [ 0*1*2*3, 4*5*6*7, 8*9*10*11, 12*13*14*15 ]
inline __m256d horizontalMultiply4( const double* rsi )
{
    __m256d a = load2( rsi, rsi + 8 );      // 0, 1, 8, 9
    __m256d b = load2( rsi + 2, rsi + 10 ); // 2, 3, 10, 11
    __m256d c = load2( rsi + 4, rsi + 12 ); // 4, 5, 12, 13
    __m256d d = load2( rsi + 6, rsi + 14 ); // 6, 7, 14, 15

    __m256d r = _mm256_unpacklo_pd( a, c );
    r = _mm256_mul_pd( r, _mm256_unpackhi_pd( a, c ) );
    r = _mm256_mul_pd( r, _mm256_unpacklo_pd( b, d ) );
    r = _mm256_mul_pd( r, _mm256_unpackhi_pd( b, d ) );
    return r;
}
```